# How to return a infinite loop of array for Plotly.JS?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I am currently learning how to use plotlyJS and am I running into trouble. I am able to create an infinite scrolling line bar using the following function

```
function getData() {
         return Math.random ();
}
```

This is great and all, but I want to infinity loop specific numbers.

I want to be able to write something like ...

```
function getData() {
         return [0.5,0.5,1,2,4.5,0.5, ... ];
}
```

My issue is, when I run this, the points are displayed, but there is no infinite scrolling effect like there would be using Math.random();. I am not sure if I should create a for loop inside of the function or find a different approach.

I am new to JavaScript so I am learning by projects and so far I have learned a lot, but I am stuck.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: well you can try and specify range for the `Math.random()` function. Using it like `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)` means that it will generate a number between 0 and 10.

Comment: I want to create a specific pattern which will be about 6 numbers ( all between 0-1 ) and that will be infinitely looped. I have looked into adding those math modifiers, but none do what I want.

Comment: Basically I want to loop over the array [ 0, 0,0,0,0,.20,.20,.85,0,0,0,0] infinitely ... similar to how Math.random() will print an infinite amount of numbers.

Comment: No, random is finite, try to print it. And array can't be infinite. But you can try to do an infinite loop to append data to that array. Up to a point where you have no more memory in your browser :)

Comment: I am not trying to generate a random number. I am trying to plot the same array ( roughly 10 numbers or so ) on a chart, but I want to do so that those same 10 specific numbers are repeated. This repetition of the array should not stop ( until browser memory can’t handle it ).

Comment: @ETHan The memory of each visitor is different, you can't take that risk. Instead, simply generate an array of 10 then do a loop to fill that array with the same values. Until a point where recall getData() again is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator function to infinitely loop over you array.

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  type: 'scatter',
};

var data = [trace1];
var chartDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {}, {});

var myArray = [0.5,1,2,4.5];

var generateData = function* (array) {
  var index = 0;
  while(true) {
    yield array[index++ % array.length];
  }
}

var xValue = 5
var dataGenerator = generateData(myArray);

var addData = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      Plotly.extendTraces(chartDiv, {x: [[xValue++]], y: [[dataGenerator.next().value]]}, [0]);
      addData();
  }, 1000);  
}

addData();
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
  <div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
```